# How to create pages from non-seriazable data(functions)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I have this JavaScript data file(`src/test/test.js`):

```js
module.exports = {
    "title": "...",
    "Number": "number1",
    "Number2": ({ number1 }) => number1 / 2,
}
```

I want to pass this file verbatim(functions preserved) to a page, so that the page can use that data to build itself. I already have the page template and everything else sorted out, I just need to find a way to pass this into the page.

---

The first approach I tried is `require`ing this file in `gatsby-node.js` and then passing it as `pageContext`.

- `gatsby-node.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

exports.createPages = ({actions, graphql}) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;

    return graphql(`
        query loadQuery {
            allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "test"}}) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        relativePath
                        absolutePath
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
            throw result.errors;
        }

        for (const node of result.data.allFile.edges.map(e => e.node)) {
            const data = require(node.absolutePath);
            createPage({
                path: node.relativePath,
                component: path.resolve('./src/templates/test.js'),
                context: data,
            });
        }
    });
};
```

- `gatsby-config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
            options: {
                name: `test`,
                path: `${__dirname}/src/test/`,
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

- `src/templates/test.js`

```js
import React from 'react';

const index = ({ pageContext }) => (
    <p>{pageContext.Number2()}</p>
);

export default index;
```

However, I get this warning when running the dev server:

```
warn Error persisting state: ({ number1 }) => number1 / 2 could not be cloned.
```

If I ignore it and try to use the function anyway, Gatsby crashes with this error:

```
WebpackError: TypeError: pageContext.Number2 is not a function
```

After searching for a while, I found this:

> The pageContext was always serialized so it never worked to pass a function and hence this isn't a bug. We might have not failed before though.
> - [Gatsby#23675](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/23675#issuecomment-623322748)

which told me this approach wouldn't work.

How could I pass this data into a page? I've considered JSON instead, however, JSON can't contain functions.

I've also tried finding a way to register a JSX object directly, however I couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the main topic, as you spotted, can't be done that way because the data is serialized.

> How could I pass this data into a page? I've considered JSON instead,
> however, JSON can't contain functions.

Well, this is partially true. You can always do something like:

```
{"function":{"arguments":"a,b,c","body":"return a*b+c;"}}
```

And then:

```
let func = new Function(function.arguments, function.body);
```

In this case, you are (de)serializing a JSON function, creating and casting a function based on JSON parameters. This approach may work in your scenario.

Regarding the JSX, I guess you can try something like:

```
for (const node of result.data.allFile.edges.map(e => e.node)) {
    const data = require(node.absolutePath);
    createPage({
        path: node.relativePath,
        component: path.resolve('./src/templates/test.js'),
        context:{
          someComponent: () => <h1>Hi!</h1>
        },
    }); 
}
```

And then:

```
import React from 'react';

const Index = ({ pageContext: { someComponent: SomeComponent} }) => (
    return <div><SomeComponent /></div>
);

export default index;
```

*Note: I don't know if it's a typo from the question but `index` should be capitalized as `Index`*

In this case, you are aliasing the `someComponent` as `SomeComponent`, which is a valid React component.

Comment: Thanks! I used the first approach. I also tried the second but I couldn't use JSX in `gatsby-node.js`. Also yeah the index is a typo, I'm still getting around react and I didn't realize it would use the exported variable's name rather than the file